# atoi function on command line arguments

Tags: c, linux, unix, command-line

I have a problem with atoi function, when i use it, it returns 0 instead of the wanted number i already know the string shouldn't contain letters but still it wont work.

so here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
         int i;

         if (argc != 6){
        printf("the arguments must be 6 to execute.\n");
        exit(0);
         }


         char* useLru = argv[1];
         char* inputFile = argv[2];
         char* outputFile = argv[3];
         char* n = argv[4];
         char* m = argv[5];

         int a = atoi(n);
         int b = atoi(m);

         printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n",useLru,inputFile,outputFile,a,b);

        return 0;
    }
```

this is my input from command line:

```
 ./Memo ‫‪1‬‬ ‫‪intput.txt‬‬ ‫‪output.txt‬‬ ‫‪1000‬‬ ‫‪50‬‬
```

and this is the output i get:

```
1‬‬
intput.txt‬‬
output.txt‬‬
0
0
```

problem is with a and b why they print zeros?

Comment: Use a debugger to inspect the arguments, inspect n and m and inspect a and b.

Comment: When I copy/paste your command text, it contains unprintable characters (that I can't see on this page, or in the edit). But when I type the input myself, it works as expected.

Comment: @vivek, `argv[0]` is the program name.

Comment: The program code works as intended and there's no error in the C source

Comment: what happens if you `printf("*%s*\n*%s*\n", n, m);` or `printf("*%s*\n*%s*\n", argv[4], argv[5]);`

Comment: well from what i know index 0 is the executable file name so there is no need to use it.

Comment: it prints the numbers but as strings i need them as integers

Comment: you do not need `n` or `m`... `atoi(argv[4])` should work as well

Comment: maybe you have a *stray* define... try `#undef atoi` after the includes and/or examine the preprocessor output (`gcc -E ...`)

Comment: yeah i know that but same problem.

Comment: thought if i added a and b before maybe it will help

Comment: The problem is the extra unprintable charaters as @WeatherVane pointed out, the code itself is fine, not optimal because of extra unneeded variables and assignments, but fine nonetheless.

Comment: For example,the last argument which should be `50` is showing as comprising characters (hex) `‫‪3F 3F 35 30` which is strange, because the `3F` is an ASCII `?` character, but where I pasted it in the console it is `?` enclosed in a box.

Comment: what do you mean by "the extra unprintable characters" like  n and m?

Comment: Right, WeatherVane, @anastaciu ... https://ideone.com/vf6bX2

Comment: guys thank you that was true apparently there was unprintable characters there i tried to retype the command in the command line  again and it works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copy/paste the input you give to my test program, this is what it shows on the terminal

[image]

My program is called `test`.
The function `atoi` is going to fail at the first character (not a digit).

The extra characters are invisible in your question, and on it's editing page.

Comment: `./Memo ÔÇ½ÔÇ¬1ÔÇ¼ÔÇ¼ ÔÇ½ÔÇ¬intput.txtÔÇ¼ÔÇ¼ ÔÇ½ÔÇ¬output.txtÔÇ¼ÔÇ¼ ÔÇ½ÔÇ¬1000ÔÇ¼ÔÇ¼ ÔÇ½ÔÇ¬50` wih a simple printf test program.

Comment: yeah thank you i deleted the spaces between my inputs and retyped them it works fine.